Изменение переменной через if в python
user_data = bool(input("Enter number: "))

isHappy = True

if not isHappy:
    print ("User satisfied")


if user_data == 5:
     isHappy = False  

Нужно, чтобы при ведении числа 5 переменная isHappy менялась на false, и в терминал выводилось User satisfied

Дело в порядке выполнения кода...
Вот вам исправленный код:
user_data = int(input("Enter number: "))

isHappy = True

if user_data == 5:
    isHappy = False

if not isHappy:
    print("User satisfied")

Как видите, я просто поменял местами условия. Важ же сначала надо проверить, равно ли число 5, а затем проверить, доволен ли пользователь.
Ну, я также заменил тип для input с bool на int — мы же вводим число.
P. S. вы, кстати, уверены, что не счастливый пользователь это satisfied? Вам бы как Python, так и английски бы подтянуть, а то все несчастные у вас в коде будут счастливыми, как в We Happy Few...

Да я совсем другой код писал, просто в голову взбрело: "А почему бы не попробовать так?". Я всё такие новичок, и пробую что-то для собственного понимания

И да, спасибо за ответ

@qwertyx, без проблем, всегда пожалуйста

@NowhereMan, нет, именно We Happy Few)) Но и это тоже в тему( ?)))) ) Суть, я думаю, передал))
